# How do I render an object in Vue.js after getting it with an AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, symfony

Let's say I have this html:

```html
<div id="app">
        <h2>List of Products</h2>
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Category</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr v-for="product in products">
                <td>${product.name}$</td>
                <td>${product.price}$</td>
                <td>${product.category}$</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

And a Vue script like this:

```js
        var app = new Vue({
            delimiters: ['${', '}$'],
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                //instead of this hardcoded result I'd like to get this array after sending a request
                products: [
                    { name: "Keyboard", price: 44, category: 'Accessories'},
                    { name: "Mouse", price: 20, category: 'Accessories'},
                    { name: "Monitor", price: 399, category: 'Accessories'},
                    { name: "Dell XPS", price: 599, category: 'Laptop'},
                    { name: "MacBook Pro", price: 899, category: 'Laptop'},
                    { name: "Pencil Box", price: 6, category: 'Stationary'},
                    { name: "Pen", price: 2, category: 'Stationary'},
                    { name: "USB Cable", price: 7, category: 'Accessories'},
                    { name: "Eraser", price: 2, category: 'Stationary'},
                    { name: "Highlighter", price: 5, category: 'Stationary'}
                ]
            },
        });
```

How do I send a request with AJAX to get the **products** object list and pass it on to Vue to render it after the result comes back from the request?

I would've imagined something like this, but this does not work:

```js
        let products;
        function getHello() {

            var ajaxSendRequest = $.ajax({
                url: '{{ path('get_products') }}',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json'
            });
            ajaxSendRequest.done(function (data) {
                //set the products variable to data that comes from response
                products = data;
            }).fail(function (textStatus, errorThrown) {

            });
        }
    
//after this use it in vue
```

I do not have much experience with stuff like this, so if this cannot be done, what is the right way to accomplish the same thing? (get data from api and then render it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first create a Vue method for your ajax code.

Methods are defined within your app like this:

```
methods: {
    getHello() {
        ...
    }
},
```

The methods property goes inside your Vue instance, same as `data`, etc.

Once it's there, you can set your products by access `this.products` where `this` refers to the Vue instance of that component.

For example

```
methods: {
    getHello() {
        ...
        this.products = ajaxResponse;
    }
},
```

Then you simply use the `products` data variable within your Vue component and it is "reactive" meaning that Vue automatically tracks and updates when it is changed.

However, there's a problem. Your method you have uses a callback. From within the callback, `this` won't refer to the Vue instance so instead you need to do something like this

```
methods: {
    getHello() {
        const $vm = this;
        ...
            // Inside your callback
            $vm.products = ajaxResponse;
    }
},
```

This allows us to set a locally scoped version of `this` that refers back to the Vue instance and access it inside our callback where the Vue `this` would have been overwritten

You would then call this method inside the `mounted()` lifecycle hook:

```
mounted() {
    this.getHello();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As simple as retrieving the data, and displaying the list. Vue will render the items, when they are ready. The this example: [Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```js
<template>
        <h2>List of Products</h2>
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Category</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(product, index) in localProducts" :key="index">
                <td>{{product.name}}</td>
                <td>{{product.price}}</td>
                <td>{{product.category}}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
  mounted(){
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.localProducts = this.serverProducts
      }, 3000)
  },
  data() {
    return {
      localProducts: undefined,
      serverProducts: [
        { name: "Keyboard", price: 44, category: 'Accessories'},
        { name: "Mouse", price: 20, category: 'Accessories'},
        { name: "Monitor", price: 399, category: 'Accessories'},
        { name: "Dell XPS", price: 599, category: 'Laptop'},
        { name: "MacBook Pro", price: 899, category: 'Laptop'},
        { name: "Pencil Box", price: 6, category: 'Stationary'},
        { name: "Pen", price: 2, category: 'Stationary'},
        { name: "USB Cable", price: 7, category: 'Accessories'},
        { name: "Eraser", price: 2, category: 'Stationary'},
        { name: "Highlighter", price: 5, category: 'Stationary'}
      ]
    }
  }
});
</script>
```